# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Juice": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

This code:

```
class Product:

    def product_stocklevel(self,product): # checks stock level for a given product
        with sqlite3.connect("db_name.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            sql = "SELECT StockLevel FROM Product WHERE Name=%s" % (product)
            cursor.execute(sql) # line that I think causes error
            product_stock = cursor.fetchone()
            return product_stock
```

The parameter `product` is given through user input, where the user would enter the name of a product they want to find the stock level for within the database for a shop.

It returns:

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Juice": syntax error (When I enter orange juice)

Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query expands to `SELECT StockLevel FROM Product WHERE Name=Orange Juice`, which isn't valid SQL.

Besides that, passing (possible) user-generated content unescaped into a SQL query is a bad idea and leaves your application open to something called "SQL injection".

Instead, use parameter substitution:

```
sql = "SELECT StockLevel FROM Product WHERE Name=?"
cursor.execute(sql, (product,))
```